# The Pop up does not disappear after submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var columnToWatch = 116;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var clickedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (clickedCell.getColumn() == columnToWatch) {
    showOptionWindow(clickedCell);
  }
}

function showOptionWindow(clickedCell) {
  var html = '<html><body><form><p>Options :</p>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="APIs/Storefront">APIs/Storefront<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Employee Rewards">Employee Rewards<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Channel Incentives">Channel Incentives<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="Customer Rewards">Customer Rewards<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option5" value="Payouts">Payouts<br>';
  html += '<br>'
  html += '<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:black; color:white;" onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.form)">';
  html += '</form></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(275);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Pillar Selection');
}

function processForm(form) {
  var selectedOptions = [];
  if (form.option1.checked) {
    selectedOptions.push(form.option1.value);
  }
  if (form.option2.checked) {
    selectedOptions.push(form.option2.value);
  }
  if (form.option3.checked) {
    selectedOptions.push(form.option3.value);
  }
  if (form.option4.checked) {
    selectedOptions.push(form.option4.value);
  }
  if (form.option5.checked) {
    selectedOptions.push(form.option5.value);
  }
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var clickedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  
  clickedCell.setValue(selectedOptions.join(', '));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You selected: ' + selectedOptions.join(', '));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().close();
}
```

When the user submits the form by clicking the submit button, the script runs the processForm function to process the form data. The selected options are stored in an array, selectedOptions, and joined into a string with a comma-space separator. The value of the clicked cell is then set to the joined string of selected options and a confirmation alert is displayed to the user.

Comment: Have tried "SpreadsheetApp.getUi().close()". Still not working.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().close()` is for server dialog.  You need to close the client dialog.  You need to include `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function).processForm(this.form)`.  Which means you need a <script> tag in you html.  It is advised you create an html file as shown in this article [withSuccessHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: The alert() dialog closes when the user presses the ok button.  I think you want the modal dialog to close too.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use an installable onEdit trigger:

```
function showOptionWindow() {
  var html = '<html><body><form><p>Options :</p>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="APIs/Storefront">APIs/Storefront<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Employee Rewards">Employee Rewards<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Channel Incentives">Channel Incentives<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="Customer Rewards">Customer Rewards<br>';
  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="option5" value="Payouts">Payouts<br>';
  html += '<br>'
  html += '<input type="button" value="Submit" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:black; color:white;" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((v) => {google.script.host.close();}).processForm(this.parentNode)"/>';
  html += '</form></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(275);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Pillar Selection');
}

function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && sh.getName() == "Sheet0") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    showOptionWindow(e.range);
  }
}

function processForm(obj) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
  var selectedOptions = [];
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option1")) {
    selectedOptions.push(obj.option1);
  }
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option2")) {
    selectedOptions.push(obj.option2);
  }
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option3")) {
    selectedOptions.push(obj.option3);
  }
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option4")) {
    selectedOptions.push(obj.option4);
  }
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option5")) {
    selectedOptions.push(obj.option5);
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(selectedOptions));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var clickedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  
  clickedCell.setValue(selectedOptions.join(', '));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You selected: ' + selectedOptions.join(', '));
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to close the modal dialog.  I have split the html into its own file to better manage the html code.

Code.gs

```
function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_Test");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Test");
}
```

HTML_Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>Options :</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="APIs/Storefront">APIs/Storefront<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Employee Rewards">Employee Rewards<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Channel Incentives">Channel Incentives<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="Customer Rewards">Customer Rewards<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="option5" value="Payouts">Payouts<br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:black; color:white;" onclick="clickSubmit(this.form)">
    </form>
    <script>
      function clickSubmit(form) {
        try {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
            function() {
              google.script.host.close();
            }
          ).processForm(form);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```